# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, option-type

I am new to code and I am not sure how to get rid of my optional values here. I read somewhere that this could be my problem. any help would be great!

I have been following this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qyy8pJd4IWU

```
@IBAction func dropPhoto(sender: AnyObject) {

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let thumbnail = image.resizedImageWithContentMode(UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit, bounds: CGSizeMake(400, 400), interpolationQuality: CGInterpolationQuality.High)
    let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail)
    let base64EncodedImage = imgData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())

    let uniqueReference = firebase?.childByAutoId()
    uniqueReference!.setValue(base64EncodedImage)

    let key = uniqueReference?.key
    _ = mapView.userLocation.location
    geofire!.setLocation(mapView.userLocation.location,forKey: key)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see this error, look for "!"s

There are two lines here that contain a force-unwrap

```
geofire!.setLocation(mapView.userLocation.location,forKey: key)
```

and

```
 uniqueReference!.setValue(base64EncodedImage)
```

you should be able to fix it by simply replacing the ! with a ? , e.g.

```
geofire?.setLocation(mapView.userLocation.location,forKey: key)
```

which will cause setLocation to be called only if geoFire is a real value, otherwise if you want to also handle the nil case, the swift way is:

```
if let geoFire = geoFire {
      geoFire.setLocation(mapView.userLocation.location, forKey: key)
}
else{
     *do something*
}
```

Comment: hmmm I replaced the ! with a ? and it did not work... where do I add the if statement you mentioned in my current code?

Comment: Ive been following this tutorial for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qyy8pJd4IWU

Comment: Just replace the geofire line with the if let statement

Comment: Make sure geoFire is actually created before this is run. that is likely the problem.

Comment: Im still getting the same error. should I be replacing all of the ! with ? in my code?

Comment: didn't see the other !, look at  uniqueReference!.setValue(base64EncodedImage) and try replacing that ! with a ?

Comment: I'm sorry I am still pretty new to this what do you mean make sure geofire is actually created?

Comment: Where are you getting the geofire object from?

Comment: In your case, you likely should replace all the ! with ?, but that is not true for all cases in general.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an `assert` or `precondition` checking firebase and geofire at the beginning of the function. Here is a third approach that will check those values and stop execution on your debug builds but otherwise simply return on release builds. That will make the later method calls into firebase and geofire safe.

You will still need to identify why one of your references is unexpectedly nil and handle that case. Maybe never call this image picker function in the first place or simply remove the `assertFailure` statements and let the function return silently without doing anything. Your choice.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {
    guard let firebase = firebase else {
       assertionFailure("Missing Firebase reference")
       return
    }
    guard let geofire = geofire else {
       assertionFailure("Missing Geofire reference")
       return
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let thumbnail = image.resizedImageWithContentMode(UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit, bounds: CGSizeMake(400, 400), interpolationQuality: CGInterpolationQuality.High)
    let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail)
    let base64EncodedImage = imgData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())

    uniqueReference = firebase.childByAutoId()
    uniqueReference.setValue(base64EncodedImage)
    geofire.setLocation(mapView.userLocation.location,forKey: uniqueReference.key)
}
```

Comment: I got a ton of errors when I tried to put this before the beginning of the function...

Comment: Try again. I had wrapped my function in my own view controller class. Just use the function. I have updated my code snippet.